# Filling the Unit Disk With Non-overlapping Rectangles

Tags: rectangles

It intuitively seems to be true that no finite set of non-overlapping rectangles can fill the unit disk. Is this proposition really true? If so, how can one prove it?

Comment: If the rectangles are required to be inside the disk, "non-overlapping" seems to be unnecessary (and if the rectangles are not required to be inside the disk, the statement is plainly false anyway).

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Find an infinite set of points, such that any 3 cannot be covered by a rectangle contained within the unit disc.